# Why is ghostscript much faster with pdfmark /BP, /EP, /SP?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

We have some legacy code that I am struggling to understand - the original author is gone.

Apparently, Ghostscript PS to PDF conversion is very slow for certain files but putting object definitions as below speeds it up immensely (we are talking 8+ hours down to 8.5 minutes for a ~20,000 page file whereas Adobe Distiller takes ~20 minutes on the original with default options).

**Original file extract (created with PReS):**

```
/@GP
{
  save exch mark exch
  execform
  cleartomark restore
} bd
...
gsave 0.62 0.62 scale @TestGraphic @GP grestore
```

Where @TestGraphic is an EPS image. This doesn't seem important as other programs use different non-EPS images with similar issues.

**Modified file:**

```
[/_objdef {new_graphic} /BBox [0 0 595 842] /BP pdfmark
@TestGraphic @GP
[/EP pdfmark
...
gsave 0.62 0.62 scale 
[ {new_graphic} /SP pdfmark
grestore
```

We have seen similar behaviour on both Unix and Windows over various `gs` versions. The timings were conducted with fairly standard options:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin32c" \
   -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o test.pdf test.ps
```

I'm not too interested in diagnosing why it is slow (it would take a long time to remove sensitive data from the file but I can try if it's really needed) but rather what benefit the objection definition and pdfmark commands provide.

The original script referenced http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5113.Forms.pdf and was designed to enable execform caching on certain printer RIPs and Distiller (which each struggled with large full-colour images), however Ghostscript didn't support execform caching so this alternate pdfmark technique was adopted, with no notes on why.

**Edit: Added gist of form definition with data removed:**

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/676924d451188276053b9b472279e382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely using older versions of Ghostscript. Your original fragment uses PostScript forms, which is unusual, and older versions of the pdfwrite device did not preserve forms as forms, but instead 'unrolled' the form definition each time it was used.

This will, unsurprisingly, result in *much* larger output files, especially if, as is likely, the form is the majority of the content and is used on every page.

The pdfmark code defines a PDF object, and then references that object each time. Only one object, so the file is much smaller, so you spend **much** less time assembling it, and copying identical data 20,000 times.

Of course, new versions of the pdfwrite device will preserve forms, so most likely the benefit of creating and referencing the PDF object directly is long gone.

Its nothing to do with caching of forms (not 'execform caching'), its to do with whether a form in the input PostScript is preserved as a form in the output PDF or not.

By the way, it is important to understand why the performance is poor, wihtout that you can't possibly understand why another approach is faster.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I tested with various versions including 9.21 (command as shown above). Still definitely got the benefit with pdfmark but it may be due to an uncommon way of constructing the form. It will take a little while to unroll all the redefined commands to see what it is really doing. There were 30 forms in total, some thumbnail sized and others 75% of the page. Some pages had just one others had multiple. I will dig deeper tomorrow.

Comment: I'd need to see an example to be able to give a full reply. Current versions should be able to respect forms, but to be honest, the pdfmark approach is almost certainly going to be the most efficient anyway, as it does not rely on the device 'spotting' the form, it explicitly names it and uses the named form. No heuristics, no checking to see if its identical to an existing form etc etc

Comment: I have added a gist showing how the form is defined, I know it's a longshot but something might jump out at you. For now we'll stick with the pdfmarks and I will look into it more next week if possible. I can also raise a bug on the GS bugzilla if you feel like looking into this more.

Comment: I'm actually on vacation right now, won't be back at my desk until next Monday. At a quick glance that doesn't look entirely legal for form usage, since forms are required to be atomic, they must not depend on the interpreter state, nor alter the interpreter state. Forms are intended for, well, forms, not for isolating chunks of program code. Rather than reading a random EPS, you should turn the EPS into a form definition. In all honesty it looks to me like that's probably the problem, and there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Looking at it, this appears to be simply an (inefficient) means of turning an EPS into a form. Without seeing how the form is later used I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work as expected with Ghostscript, but the skeleton presented is too much reduced to tell for sure. 30 different forms sounds, well sub-optimal to me, but I have no clue as to the content really.

Comment: The first snippet in the question (including the call to @GP) is how they are called. They seem to exist as a vector image format for graphs/logos/etc. For many similar tools I've come across, EPS is the only such image format supported and they all do something weird like this. At this point I think we know enough to at least know it won't break anything, but if you have more insights that would be appreciated.

Comment: I did see the way these are called, but that wasn't quite what I meant when I said 'how the form is later used'. Although that code shows me how the form is called, it tells me nothing about what the content is, whether there are multiple forms per page, if the graphics state changes between invocations etc. The use of pdfmarks will work **unless** you try to run the same PostScript program to an ordinary PostScript RIP, say for printing the content, in which case it simply won't print that content (and may throw an error depending on the rest of the program).

Comment: The only way I could say more would be to analyse the content in more detail and to be honest that's a big job which we probably wouldn't undertake for a free user, especially if the problem is simply performance rather than an actual fault.